Unexpected java.util.Optional.orElseGet() evaluation
Doing these 2 equivalent printouts I'm getting different results:
String text = "hi";
String text2 = null;
System.out.println(Optional.ofNullable(text).map(String::length).orElseGet(text2::length));
System.out.println(Optional.ofNullable(text).map(String::length).orElseGet(() -> text2.length()));

In the first case I'm getting a nullpointerexception, but in the second case I'm just getting "2" by console.
I understood the orElseGet part was never going no be evaluated if the Optional.ofNullable() part is not null, but I'm surprised to find that it is depending on the format of the functional expression used.
Why is this happening? I'm using java 11.0.21.
Thanks.

This is kind of the "opposite" situation from the duplicate target, but the problem is the same. You are using a method reference expression on null (text2 in this case).

@Sweeper the interesting part here is that the method reference in orElseGet should not even be executed since the Optional is not null/empty.

@f1sh The method that the method reference is referencing is not called, but the method reference expression is still evaluated (since orElseGet is called and its arguments need to be evaluated), and that is where the NPE gets thrown.

Excuse me, Sweeper: do you mean the NPE is being thrown in the internal transformation from "text2::length" to "() -> text2.length()"?

orElseGet(text2::length) is evaluated directly as orElseGet without a Supplier is basically for returning a constant static value, which needs to be present up-front. Whereas orElseGet(() -> text2.length()) is evaluated lazily due to that being a Supplier.

Thanks for your explanation, M. Deinum. Still I don't understand what "is evaluated for returning a constant static value" means, as it still needs a Supplier. Can you please give more details?
